# Spring Data Elasticsearch automatically reconnect

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot app where I use `ElasticsearchTemplate` to connect to my ElasticSearch. However when it works and I turn off the Elasticsearch, everytime I use a `ElasticTemplate` method I get an `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException`. It's fine because the ElasticSearch is not working.

However when the ElasticSearch works back I still get an `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException` as if this is not trying to reconnect but once it lost connection I need to restart my whole app.

How to solve this ? Is there a way to make it try to reconnect to ealsticSearch after ES was down ?

Answer (score 1):

The TransportClient sends a heartbeat signal every 5 sec in order to verify the
node is alive and drop it if not.

With sniffing enabled the client will connect to newly discovered nodes or to an old node coming up again.

So setting the"client.transport.sniff" property in the TransportClient settings to true should help. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.5/transport-client.html

BTW: Consider switching to a rest client as the usage of the transport client will prevent you from upgrading to future elasticsearch releases (https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients)